# DragDetect (IntPtr, Point) from user32.dll eqivalent in mono?

Tags: c#, mono, pinvoke

Does anybody know managed code for the mentioned p/invoke call to use it with mono?
Is there a linux lib that provides similar functionality as the user32.dll on windows does?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a direct equivalent for DragDirect call for x11\GTK, but you can have the same functionality with `Gdk.Pointer.Grab` and `Gdk.Pointer.Ungrab` methods. Capture the mouse pointer whenever you need then track mouse movement and release once user hits Escape or releases the mouse or mouse is out of the drag rectangle.

Below is a small example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow () : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build ();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }

    protected virtual void OnWidgetEvent (object o, Gtk.WidgetEventArgs args)
    {   
        if (args.Event is Gdk.EventMotion && args.Event.Type==Gdk.EventType.MotionNotify)
        {
            Gdk.EventMotion eventMotion = (Gdk.EventMotion)args.Event; 
            Console.WriteLine("mouse move {0} {1}", eventMotion.X, eventMotion.Y);
        }
        else if (args.Event is Gdk.EventKey && args.Event.Type==Gdk.EventType.KeyPress)
        {
            Gdk.EventKey eventKey = (Gdk.EventKey)args.Event;
            if (eventKey.Key==Gdk.Key.Escape)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("mouse pointer ungrab");
                Gtk.Grab.Remove(this);
                Gdk.Pointer.Ungrab(Gtk.Global.CurrentEventTime);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnButton1WidgetEvent (object o, Gtk.WidgetEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Event is Gdk.EventButton && args.Event.Type==Gdk.EventType.ButtonPress)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("mouse pointer grab");
            Gdk.Pointer.Grab(this.GdkWindow, true,
                Gdk.EventMask.ButtonPressMask | Gdk.EventMask.ButtonReleaseMask | Gdk.EventMask.PointerMotionMask | Gdk.EventMask.EnterNotifyMask | Gdk.EventMask.LeaveNotifyMask, 
                null, null, Gtk.Global.CurrentEventTime); 
            Gtk.Grab.Add (this);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow UI declaration:

```
  <widget class="Gtk.Window" id="MainWindow" design-size="400 300">
    <property name="MemberName" />
    <property name="Title" translatable="yes">MainWindow</property>
    <property name="WindowPosition">CenterOnParent</property>
    <signal name="DeleteEvent" handler="OnDeleteEvent" />
    <signal name="WidgetEvent" handler="OnWidgetEvent" />
    <child>
      <widget class="Gtk.Fixed" id="fixed1">
        <property name="MemberName" />
        <property name="HasWindow">False</property>
        <child>
          <widget class="Gtk.Button" id="button1">
            <property name="MemberName" />
            <property name="CanFocus">True</property>
            <property name="Type">TextOnly</property>
            <property name="Label" translatable="yes">GtkButton</property>
            <property name="UseUnderline">True</property>
            <signal name="WidgetEvent" handler="OnButton1WidgetEvent" />
          </widget>
          <packing>
            <property name="X">165</property>
            <property name="Y">125</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </widget>
    </child>
  </widget>
```

more details on mouse pointer handling in GTK here: [The Mouse Pointer](http://developer.gnome.org/doc/GGAD/sec-gdkcursor.html)

hope this helps, regards

Comment: at first thanks a lot. but...does that mean that every window in which i use the grap has to be a : Gtk.Window?

Comment: that means I have to change ALL my windows when running my C# on linux?

Comment: I guess you're using Mono WinForms. Linux implementation is built on top of x11. In my example I'm using GdkWindow which is a wrapper on top of the x11 window. Besides GTK is open source, you can just check what gdk_pointer_grab is doing and do the same thing when on Linux or built for Linux

Comment: your second idea sounds good. I'll try having a look into gdk_pointer_grab